# Templated arguments causes inability to "Find function"

Tags: multithreading, class, templates, c++11

I'm trying to write some code that can execute a class member function in a separate thread, but with some added code for checking odds and ends before and after the thread has executed.

For this I'm using the std::bind and std::thread functionality of c++11 in VS2012.

All this works well if I fix the arguments the class member function can have to e.g. *void**, but if I try to template that, I get an error.

**Overview of Code**

I have a simple class containing two functions, which will be executed in a thread. They differ in arguments and name.

The class I'm creating has a templated constructor and a function, which executes the functions of the previous class, but with the ability to perform it's own checks/notifications if the thread does/does not finish.

Finally the main function is simply to test the code.

**The Code**

Include Part:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>
    #include <thread>
    #include <functional>

    using namespace std;
```

Class to be executed:

```
    class k1
    {
    public:
        k1( int nVal = 0 ) : _val(nVal){};
        ~k1(){};

        void doFunc( void * pParam ){
            cout << "Val in class = " << _val << ", param = " << pParam << "\n";
        }

        void doFunc2( float pParam ){
            cout << "Val in class = " << _val << ", param = " << pParam << "\n";
        }

        int _val;
    };
    typedef shared_ptr<k1> PK;
```

Thread Handle Class

```
    class H
    {
    public:
        void controlFunction( std::function<void(void)> callRef ){
            cout << "Before calling\n";
            callRef();
            cout << "After calling\n";
        }

        template<class T, typename ParamType> // Constructor for any type of class function - void * parameter as only input
        H( void(T::* pFunction)(ParamType *), T * pClass, ParamType pParam ){
            std::function<void(void)> _call = std::bind( pFunction, pClass, pParam );
            _thread = shared_ptr<std::thread>( new thread( &H::controlFunction, this, _call ));
        }


        ~H( void ){
            _thread->join();
        }

        shared_ptr<thread> _thread;
    };
    typedef shared_ptr<H> PH;
```

Main Function:

```
    int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        PK k = make_shared<k1>( 12 );

        int i1 = 2;
        float f1 = 1.0f;

        PH p = PH( new H(&k1::doFunc, k.get(), &i1 ));
        PH p2 = PH( new H(&k1::doFunc2, k.get(), f1 ));

        return 0;
    }
```

The error that comes out is:

*error C2660: 'H::H' : function does not take 3 arguments*

Thanks in advance!

/Henrik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm *guessing* that you get the error on the second line where you create a `H` object taking `k1::doFunc2` as argument. The probable reason for the error is because `k1::doFunc2` doesn't take a pointer for argument, while the member function pointer argument in the `H` constructor expects it to.

There is also some problems with the first line, when you declare the `p` variable. This is because then the `ParamType` template type can be deduced to be *either*  `int` *or* `int*`. The reason for this is because the member function pointer have `ParamType *`, while the third argument to the constructor uses non-pointer `ParamType` but you pass a pointer here (`&i1`).

Comment: Well called! This only partially solves my problem. The one with the float now compiles as it should, but the pointer part still gives me the same error. Even if I add '*' to the first and last argument of the H constructor.

Comment: Ah, I had to explicitly make the void* conversion or change the class function to a "int *". Thanks!